# check for a Specific date format and a string

Tags: powershell

I have an input file which consist of a content as shown below

> 07-07 09:22:20 WARN [EmailMessageRecord] - Unable to load HTML Body
>   from external file: D:\EmailConnector\Output\H0000001.html

I would like to check whether the date format is like this format `07-07 09:22:20(MM-DD HH:MM:ss)` and next string is `WARN`
 Could you help me how can i code this in Powershell?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This solution uses [Select-String](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849903.aspx) with a regex but ignores the datetime format. However, it could still fit for you:

```powershell
$input = '07-07 09:22:20 WARN [EmailMessageRecord] - Unable to load HTML Body from external file: D:\EmailConnector\Output\H0000001.html'
$input | Select-String -Quiet -Pattern '^\d{2}-\d{2}\s\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}\sWARN'
```